# Jquery Format HTML Table in a Given Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to display query contents in HTMl using following jquery

```
    $tableSearch = $('#table-search');
    $tableSearch.html('<tr><th>Name</th><tr><th>Hours</tr></th><tr><th>MB</th></tr>'); 
    result.forEach(function(row) {
     $('#table-search tr').append('<td>'+ row.Date +'</td>'+'<td>'+ row.Hours+'</td>'+'<td>'+ row.MB+'</td>'); 
        });
```

**But it gives the result like below**

[image]

**Actually I want the result like this**
[image]

How to format those values like above.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] with relevant input

Comment: Also there is no way `<tr><th>Name</th><tr><th>Hours</tr></th><tr><th>MB</th></tr>` will give you a vertical header on its own

Comment: Lastly there is no PHP issue here unless you want to do the code on the server

Comment: How to get this values in Php @mplungjan

Comment: they come from somewhere. The logic in PHP would be the same as in JS. So you need to make a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define class or id on `<tr>` tag of table header row, And then append the data as class/id wise row.

```
$tableSearch = $('#table-search');
    $tableSearch.html('<tr class="tr1"><th>Name</th><tr class="tr2"><th>Hours</tr></th><tr class="tr3"><th>MB</th></tr>'); 
    result.forEach(function(row) {
    $('#table-search .tr1').append('<td>'+ row.Date +'</td>');
     $('#table-search .tr2').append('<td>'+ row.Hours+'</td>');
     $('#table-search .tr3').append('<td>'+ row.MB+'</td>');
   });
```